# How do I hide my API keys while simultaneously letting my app having access to them in Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, deployment, api-key

I have created a Node application and I'm finally ready to deploy it to Heroku. In the application I'm using several API keys. These I have put in a separate file and using exports to retrieve them from around my application. I then added the APIkey file to .gitignore. I've since then deployed my application to Heroku but it didn't work.

Here's my log while trying to be opening my app:

> 2018-12-19T23:38:14.937951+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
>   command `npm start`
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:16.868566+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:16.868584+00:00 app[web.1]: > weather-app@1.0.0 start
>   /app
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:16.868587+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:16.868588+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:17.072318+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting geocode
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:17.291050+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   starting to crashed
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:17.274770+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
>   status 1
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:25.032443+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
>   command `npm start`
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:28.893393+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:28.893409+00:00 app[web.1]: > weather-app@1.0.0 start
>   /app
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:28.893411+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:28.893413+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.228923+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting geocode
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.529491+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.529503+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.529504+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.529506+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.529508+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module
>   '../APIkeys'
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.529510+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   Function.Module._resolveFilename
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.529512+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.529514+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.529517+00:00 app[web.1]: at require
>   (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.529519+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.
>   (/app/geocode/geocode.js:4:16)
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.529521+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.529522+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.529524+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.529526+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.529528+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.546841+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.547798+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.549579+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
>   weather-app@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.549782+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.550057+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.550295+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the
>   weather-app@1.0.0 start script.
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.550513+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably
>   not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output
>   above.
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.562868+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.563140+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log
>   of this run can be found in:
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.563302+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
>   /app/.npm/_logs/2018-12-19T23_38_29_554Z-debug.log
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.673736+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   starting to crashed
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:29.648927+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with 
>   status 1
>
> 2018-12-19T23:38:51.067585+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=desolate-eyrie-
>   91272.herokuapp.com request_id=a200b9fa-8f0b-4d33-a1d2-eb990b0bd035 fwd="158.248.240.182" dyno= connect= service=

Now this is my first real application so my experience with this is limited and most likely my approach is incorrect. My question is: if my APIkeys shouldn't get added and therefore hidden in my .gitignore then what approach should I use to hide my keys but still making Heroku capable of running my app? My application works locally by doing `npm start` with the app.js.

Let me know if further information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to let you know that I've resolved my question. I had misunderstood what .gitignore actually did. Instead I've used a simple enviroment file and it works as a charm